# What to do with !address -filter Windbg

Tags: c++, windbg, crash-dumps

I am currently looking into an issue where an application is using alot of private memory for a C++ app. It looks like alot is in commited and reserve memory based on the dump analysis.

I use Windbg. Is there any way I can see what excactly is in commited and reserve memory? I have narrowed it down to one specific heap.

My theory is that it's not being released. I cannot live debug, I only have dumps to go on.

I have already used the command !address -filter and get a pretty little out put, but how do i move forward?

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `!heap -s` command to get memory usage info in WinDbg.  There is a tutorial on Leak Detection with windbg [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/MemoryLeak.aspx).

Comment: Yes I have used that command howerver, it doesn't provide me the stacks to the heap addresses.

Comment: @Andy: What do you mean with "the stacks to the heap addresses"?

Comment: I have the heap that I suspect being the issue.

Comment: I don't understand what it is you want to know? unless your app creates a heap explicitly besides the default heap, that !heap will show you all memory info you can know about your app

Comment: Ok, the application is causing virtual memeory to increase.  Alot is allocated to reserve and commited.  I want to be able to view what's in that heap.

Comment: With windbg you can only see hex bytes of the heap content, is that going to tell you what's in there?  The tutorial I linked really explains very well how you can debug a memory leak with windbg, I suggest you have a look.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways how you can diagnoze memory leaks:

- Using heap stack trace, and then [examining process dump in WinDbg](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/clr/thread/63bd564a-7278-475f-89e9-b1634a71569f)
- Taking snapshots of process memory state using [UMDH tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343).

The later option (UMDH tool) is part of WinDbg package and is usually the easiest option to investigate memory leaks. Both options are actually based on the same feature, which is an ability of NT heap to keep call stacks at the allocation along with the allocated entry.

Note that besides leaking memory in heaps, you might have other types of leaks that would result in increase of commited memory space. For example you might have called VirtualAlloc directly and forgot to VirtualFree it.

Comment: +1 for UMDH - I found UMDH is be the easiest AND most reliable out of many tools that I've tried.  Just a tip if you are planning on using it.  I found that in some cases it refuses to properly resolve symbols no matter what you try.  If that's your case, don't bother with symbols, instead after you do the diff report, take a snapshot dump of your process and use WinDbg to manually go to the address locations in UMDH stack.  That works every time.

Comment: Second tip: There was one instance in the last 8 years where I investigated a memory leak and UMDH didn't work.  Turns out if call malloc (or HeapAlloc) with a request big enough, it'll skip the heap and go straight to VirtualAlloc and those allocations are not traced by UMDH.  I ended up putting conditional breakpoints on 2 (or 4, don't remember) places inside ntdll that would break whenever request was larger than a threshold.  Just follow any memory allocation to see which function in ntdll they end up in.  Good luck